# Missing dependencies after create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I've just created my first, simple `React` app using the `create-react-app` command and now when I  type `npm` list i get:

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev 
|| >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.20.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev 
|| >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.20.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev 
|| >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta, required by tsutils@3.20.0
```

What does that mean, how can I solve it and why such problems occurs while doing some automatic installation?

Comment: Don't worry about it, CRA has bumped their TS dependency to 4.1.2 as of right now. `tsutils` just needs to catch up. Here's the [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6834)

Comment: @AppCity I'm using typescript